# how do I properly fire this function only if the previous has successfully been completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I am attempting to do a series of actions that has a user logout then redirect them to a home page, using parse in Javascript. Here is the logic:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logout").on("click", function (e) {
      //logout current user
      if ( Parse.User.current() ) {
        Parse.User.logOut();

        // check if really logged out
        if (Parse.User.current()) {
          console.log("Failed to log out!");
        } else {
        // redirect page

          window.location.replace("home-screen.html");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

However most times when I logout, back in my parse server, the user session hasn't been destroyed. But I noticed when I remove the `window.location` action, the user session is destroyed every single time successfully.

So how do I edit my function to say "on click, log user out and ONLY if done successfully THEN redirect page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.User.logout() returns a promise. Redirect the user after the promise is resolved successfully.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logout").on("click", function (e) {
      //logout current user
      if ( Parse.User.current() ) {
        Parse.User.logOut()
          .then(function () {
            window.location.replace("home-screen.html");
          });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks, yeah I also attempted to use the `.then` selector but I knew I was using it wrong haha.